# SQL: How to get Max of Variable (per category of another variable)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, max

**Situation**: I have a table containing the data field `my_number` and `my_location` (among many other data fields). I'm only concerned about those two fields. I want to select the maximum '`my_number`' for each '`my_location`'. There are only 3 possible my_location options but numerous possible my_number. All variables represented by numbers.

I was researching correlated subquery but I do not know how to use them. Maybe joins could work?
I am trying to learn different ways, effective ways to complete this task.

Comment: Instead of saying how you tried ,show some code,some sample DML and expected output:you can start from here:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
     MAX(my_number) as Max_Number,
     my_location
FROM 
     TABLE
GROUP BY 
     my_location
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  my_location
,       MAX(my_number) my_number_max
FROM    My_Table
GROUP BY my_location
```

See: [MAX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187751.aspx), [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)

Comment: Wow. You are awesome and answered so quickly. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, I think @Aldrin was slightly faster :P Don't forget to accept the answer which solved your problem

Comment: I tried what you said and it seems to work. I added a check for a specific my_number. The results look correct. This is what I wrote.  <br/> {SELECT MAX(my_number) as maxnumber, my_location  <br/> FROM tables  <br/> Where my_number = '123'  <br/> GROUP BY my_location}

Comment: I am not sure how to accept answers. But I upvoted the responses. I am a first timer if it is not painfully obvious. I tried to show you what I added in the previous comment to no avail.

Comment: There is a check mark in the upper left of the answer which you can check to accept (it will turn green)